# How can I render a template in a function that has on_connect() dedicator for mqtt?

Tags: python, flask, mqtt

First of all, sorry for sloppy format of my question.

What I am trying to do is to render a web using flask with by raspberrypi.

In the web, I need to put some data that that I got from mqtt message.

My current status is I have gotten the data in `handle_cunnect()` function and I am trying to render a template with the data, but I am keep failing it. Here is the code. I have removed insufficient parts and parts that contain personal informations.

```
from flask import *
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt
import jinja2

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = 'MY_BROKER' # use the free broker from HIVEMQ 
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = 1883 # default port for non-tls connection 
app.config['MQTT_USERNAME'] = '' # set the username here if you need authentication for the broker 
app.config['MQTT_PASSWORD'] = '' # set the password here if the broker demands authentication 
app.config['MQTT_KEEPALIVE'] = 5 # set the time interval for sending a ping to the broker to 5 seconds 
app.config['MQTT_TLS_ENABLED'] = False # set TLS to disabled for testing purposes

mqtt = Mqtt(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@mqtt.on_connect()
def handle_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   if rc == 0:
       print('Connected successfully')
       mqtt.subscribe("iot/dht_cds") # subscribe topic
   else:
       print('Bad connection. Code:', rc)

@mqtt.on_topic('iot/dht_cds')
def handle_mytopic(client, userdata, message):    
    print('Received message on topic {}: {}'
          .format(message.topic, message.payload.decode()))
    
    l_value = message.payload.decode()    #  I have replaced l_value with constant integer 3 at the bottom for test
    
    with app.app_context():
        template = render_template('home_cds.html', light_value = 3)
        return template

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    # setup_mqtt()
    print('Starting Webserver...') 
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I get a message at channel 'iot/dht_cds', `handle_mytopic()` function is called but it does nothing. If I add `print(template)` with the template returned by `render_template('home_cds.html', light_value = 3)`, this prints out at terminal.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>NodeMCU Control</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style='width: 300px; margin: auto; text-align: center;'>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p> Light amount is 3</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried using without with `with app.app_context():` but it also does not do anything.

I just need to print out the data on web using flask but having a big trouble.

It will be very thankful if anyone can give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

server receive data from publisher and broker on mqtt. but server don't connect to client.

if use websocket, server can connect to client.

I'm recommend to use websocket based SocketIO.

https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html